# Amazon S3 read file operation times out from Lambda function with Task timed out after 30.03 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda

This code works in .net core console on my local machine

```
await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(new GetObjectRequest { BucketName = bucketName, Key = key });
```

but same line does not work in Lambda function in aws, it times out with "Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"

I have done following

1. Increased the timeout for lambda function to 5 mins.
2. Increased the memory usage limit for lambda function.
3. Attached policy "AmazonS3FullAccess" to lambda function IAMRole.
   Also attached policy "AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess" to the same role (desperate measures)
4. Made the Bucket public for everyone.
5. Made sure bucket and function live in same region.

Still no luck, what am I doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Is the lambda in a vpc?

Comment: The VPC config could really be related to it as @Marcin pointed. But just for the sake, could you sent us the basic configuration of the lambda function and also put the section regarding the memory usage + total run time from the cloudwatch log from the lambda execution within as part of the question as well? 95% of the time this is down to the memory consumption or timeout. Let's try to confirm first if that is the case or is something else regarding the other 5% (VPC for instance). cheers,

Comment: thanks @Marcin and Lucas Barbosa. yes problem indeed was related to VPC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, need to remove VPC to make it work.

However, if you dont want to remove your VPC, do following.

1. create a new nat gateway in public subnet.
2. add a new role in private route table to allow 0.0.0.0 to nat gateway.

Ta da, now your Lambda can read files from s3 bucket. However, note that nat gateway has a cost associated with it. so it is not free option.

There is a new way of doing things. read [This](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) and apply it.